# Rewriting PHP code to Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, replace

Someone can help me to rewrite the following code to Javascript ?

```
public function replace($text)
{
    $array = array(
      '1' => '1.png',
      '2' => '2.png'
    );

    reset($array);
    while (list($code, $path) = each($array))
        $text = str_replace($code, "<img src=\"/img/$path\" />", $text);

    return $text;
}
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/default.asp or use a framework like prototypejs or jQuery and read the docs. If you know php you can do javascript, more or less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A verbatim solution:

```
function replace(text) {
  var array = {
    1: '1.png',
    2: '2.png'
  };
  for (code in array) {
    var path = array[code];
    text = text.replace(code, '<img src="/img/' + path + '" />');
  }
  return text;
}
```